# TypeError: Cannot set property 'words' of undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I have this action in my vuex store:

```
loadExercises ({commit}) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  db.collection('exercises').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const exercises = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        exercises.push({
          title: doc.data().title,
          language: doc.data().language,
          translated: doc.data().translated,
          lastOpen: doc.data().lastOpen,
          dueDate: doc.data().dueDate,
          uid: doc.data().uid,
          userId: doc.data().userId,
          words: [{ word: '', uid: '', translation: '' }]
        })
        db.collection('exercises').doc(doc.data().uid).collection('words').get()
          .then(words => {
            const wordsArray = []
            words.forEach(word => {
              wordsArray.push(word.data())
            })
            let exercise = this.getters.loadedExercise(doc.data().uid)
            exercise.words = wordsArray
          })
          .catch(error => {
            commit('setLoading', false)
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
      commit('setLoading', false)
      commit('setLoadedExercises', exercises)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      commit('setLoading', false)
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

It is supposed to fetch exercises from a firebase cloudstore db. It works on some routes but not all.

When using these two getters it works:

```
loadedExercises (state) {
  return state.loadedExercises
},
loadedExercise (state) {
  return (exerciseId) => {
    return state.loadedExercises.find(exercise => {
      return exercise.uid === exerciseId
    })
  }
}
```

But when I use these getters:

```
upcomingExercises (state, getters) {
  return getters.loadedExercises.filter(exercise => {
    return exercise.dueDate > 0
  })
},
latestExercises (state, getters) {
  return getters.loadedExercises.splice(0, 5)
},
```

it does not work I just get "TypeError: Cannot set property 'words' of undefined". What is it that I do wrong?

Comment: I suggest you `console` out and see if the property `words` do exist. To me it doesn't seem like a problem of vuex, rather it's because the data/object (that has property `words`) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you aren't returning the values back to the function.

Try replacing

`db.collection('exercises').get()`

with

`return db.collection('exercises').get()`

and

`db.collection('exercises').doc(doc.data().uid).collection('words').get()`

with

`return db.collection('exercises').doc(doc.data().uid).collection('words').get()`

Comment: It worked kinda, I get the same error for the first 5 exercises and then it works like it is supposed to. How should I fix that?

Comment: I would go with @kevguy's suggestion to add a console.log at each step in your code and see where it's failing